# cursor control for "python -i" in cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, interactive-mode, python-interactive

When using python in `cygwin`, you need to use **"python -i"** to get into interactive mode. This mode however removes my ability to use my arrow keys to go through my history.

When I push the Up-Key, the cursor goes up. When I press DELETE, the character gets deleted. I want my cursor to act like a normal Windows `CLI`; where it stays on ONE line.

Comment: when i am in cygwin i usually just type `python` to get into the shell(although this may beg the question of why are you using cygwin? instead of python for windows?)

Comment: If I use python without the -i option, I don't get anything and the output gets buffered and is never shown until you close it with ctrl-C. I'm using a python version in cygwin that was installed as a normal python exe. I'm using python inside cygwin because I need to refer to a dll build using cygwin, which can't be used inside windows alone.

Comment: Are you using the cygwin version of Python, or a native Windows install of Python?

Comment: native windows install

Comment: That's usually a bad idea. Cygwin Python builds are built to work inside the cygwin environment; native ones inside the normal cmd.exe environment. And if the reason you're using cygwin is to access a cygwin DLL… it's an even _more_ bad idea; whatever you're using the access the DLL (`ctypes` or `cffi`, or building a bindings extension module around it, or whatever) is going to segfault all over the place.

Comment: (Meanwhile, running a program from cmd.exe doesn't stop that program from accessing cygwin DLLs, and running from a cygwin shell doesn't help it do so. So if your code works—which it probably won't—it will work just as well if you start Python from the Windows CLI.)

Comment: well If I access the dll build with cygwin inside windows env, I get the following error:"The program can't start because cygwin1.dll is missing…". And the dll i'm accessing isn't a dll of cygwin, it' a dll build using cygwin (make).

Comment: hmm, adding \cygwin\bin to system path fixed it. Thanks

Comment: if that's an option for you, running Cygwin.bat instead of mintty.exe solved this for me